# How to access taskbar via keyboard-only inputs with auto-hide enabled?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

How can you access taskbar while auto-hide is enabled via tab key?  Without auto-hide, invoking Start then <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> typically sets focus onto the taskbar, but when auto-hide is enabled the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key immediately hides the taskbar and sets focus back to previous focal point, so you're unable to tab-cycle the taskbar.  Is there a better method to do so that's roughly equivalent in keystrokes/speed?

Just to be clear, that disqualifies the Num-Pad Mouse feature, short of coming up with, e.g., an .ahk script to bind it to a single-input method to toggle enable/disable *and* have the pointer spawn at a user-designated screen coordinate, or something of the likes...hopefully an easier method exists without going through that trouble.

Oh, and I'm referring to Windows 10 Pro x64 on build 1903 (shortly to be 1909).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the key combination <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. This will help you to enable the taskbar and to cycle through all icons in the taskbar, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or the same key combination again. It works even when the auto hide taskbar is enabled.

Bonus shortcut : If you want to access the stuff on the right side of the taskbar where things like time and day, volume and action center icons, volume icons are, use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Another Bonus shortcut : If you want to access the action center directly without going to the taskbar, use the key combination <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.